# I want to obtain the values of reliability != 1 by day in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I want to know how many values are different from 1 in my dataframe.

My input is like:

```
simulation, day, reliability
1, 1, 0.999
1, 2, 0.999
1, 3, 0.999
2, 1, 1
2, 2, 0.999
2, 3, 1
3, 1, 0.98
3, 2, 0.98
3, 3, 1
```

And the output should be like:

```
day, counter
1, 2
2, 3 
3, 1
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can take sum of logical values to count how many of them are different than 1 for each day.

In base R :

```
aggregate(reliability~day, df, function(x) sum(x != 1))
```

`dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%group_by(day) %>% summarise(counter = sum(reliability != 1))
```

and data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(counter = sum(reliability != 1)), day]
```

Answer (score 0):

Though Ronak has already provided an exhaustive answer, still an alternative way

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(reliability != 1) %>% group_by(day) %>% summarise(counter = n())
```